# ASp.net MVC application Windows Security Pop up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7, iis-6

All, I have an ASP.net MVC application (using DevEx controls). I have deployed to a test server via IIS. When I run the application it gives the below pop up for the home page.

testserver:1234

[image]

If I navigate to other pages, testserver:1234/page1 , testserver:1234/page2 it works. 
has anyone encountered same issue? Do you know why am I getting this pop up on home page testserver:1234. Thanks for helping out.

This how my controller looks:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ImportDataValidationErrors = new List<ImportFileRecord>();
        return View();
    }
```

and this is how routing looks:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ImportData", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Add more details, like HomeController, and actions, and if other page views are returned from different controller actions add them as well. Are you sure that you're using MVC 3 ? and IIS 6 ?

Comment: Maybe you're using DevExpress Components?

Comment: I have added Controller and Route. 
testserver:1234 gives the pop up but testserver:1234/ImportData works. Not sure why do I have the Windows Security pop up.

Comment: Are you using somewhere authorize attribute? it's looks like that you have Windows Authentication configured in IIS

Comment: I am [AuthorizeExtension(Roles = SystemRole.Administrators)]
SystemRole.Administrators are bunch of users.

Comment: If it's test project, please, create git repository and share it. Because it's quite hard to get in what's wrong in your specific case, when I can't see the whole picture.